# Building recognition in vuforia?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

normally I can make apps using image targeting or cloud recognition but now I need to use physical buildings as target so my question is does anyone know how to recognize buildings via vuforia + unity or vuforia android?

I found an app in youtube and just want to know how it should be created.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=665waHAeA1k

Comment: I would assume that the example you show simply is based on an image of the front of the building. That is fairly planar and should lead to acceptable tracking, even at angles that are not too extreme.

Comment: the video which I shared was an example about what I want to do. lets think there is a terrain and when people use the phone to look at the terrain they should see a building no matter from which angle. What I need is pictures taken from all angles and then use cloud recognition or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

With Vuforia, you need to provide "Target image" for the recognition and load the target database in Unity.  It's possible to take a photo of the building and use it as a target.  But you need to take only a photo of something that won't change over time (ex: tree, vegetation, etc.)

Comment: what about terrains? lets say I took a photo of the terrain from 1 angle so do you think it will show the marker from every angle?

Comment: @MustafaGüven Are you able to develop this application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with terrains is that it should have enough contrast so the camera can recognize it. When you upload your image to the Vuforia Target Maganer it would show a rating (from 1 to 5 starts). The greater the rate, the better the recognition would be